# NotesSession.GetDataBase method is returning null value

Tags: c#-3.0

I have a c# class which was written to read the lotus emails for any attachments and save it to the local drive.  It was working fine when I pass "" as first parameter to GetDataBase method and full path of .nsf file of my local system as second argument.  But, if I remove "" and I specify my local system full name as first argument it is returning null value.

Is it problem with any permissions?  If so, it should not work even when I pass "" as first parameter.  Otherwise, should I have any other permissions at system/server level?
Please help me in this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I could do it in the following way.  And I thought of posting it to some one can atleast not to suffer again.

Following code is to read the attachment from the lotus emails and save it to the physical location.

string lotusServerName = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Lotus_Server"].ToString();
            string lotusDBFilePath = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Lotus_DB_File_Path"].ToString();
            string password = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Password"].ToString();
            string sourceFolder = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Source_Folder"].ToString();
            string targetFolder = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Target_Folder"].ToString();
            string documentsFolder = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Documents_Folder"].ToString();

```
        //Creating the notes session and passing password
        NotesSession session = new NotesSession();
        session.Initialize(password);

        //Getting the DB instance by passing the servername and path of the mail file.  
        //third param "false" will try to check the DB availability by opening the connection
        //if it cannot open, then it returns null.
        NotesDatabase NotesDb = session.GetDatabase(lotusServerName, lotusDBFilePath, false);

        //Get the view of the source folder
        NotesView inbox = NotesDb.GetView(sourceFolder);

        //looping through each email/document and looking for the attachments
        //if any attachments found, saving them to the given specified location
        //moving the read mails to the target folder
        NotesDocument docInbox = null;
        int docCnt = inbox.EntryCount;
        for (int currDoc = 0; currDoc < docCnt; currDoc++) {
            docInbox = inbox.GetFirstDocument();
            object[] items = (object[])docInbox.Items;
            foreach (NotesItem nItem in items) {
                if (nItem.Name == "$FILE") {
                    NotesItem file = docInbox.GetFirstItem("$File");
                    string fileName = ((object[])nItem.Values)[0].ToString();
                    NotesEmbeddedObject attachfile = (NotesEmbeddedObject)docInbox.GetAttachment(fileName);

                    if (attachfile != null) {
                        attachfile.ExtractFile(documentsFolder + fileName);
                    }
                }
            }
            docInbox.PutInFolder(targetFolder, true);//"true" creates the folder if it doesn't exists
            docInbox.RemoveFromFolder(sourceFolder);
        }

        //releasing resources
        if (session != null)
            session = null;
        if (NotesDb != null)
            NotesDb = null;
        if (inbox != null)
            inbox = null;
        if (docInbox != null)
            docInbox = null;
```

Following is values read from .config file.

The above code will work properly if you alredy have lotus mail client in your system and you are able to access mails from your mail server.  You don't require any other previliges.

Comment: <appSettings>
 <add key="Lotus_Server" value="ServerName/DomainName"/>
 <add key="Lotus_DB_File_Path" value="mail\MailfileName.nsf"/>
 <add key="Password" value="password"/>
 <add key="Source_Folder" value="Personal"/>
 <add key="Target_Folder" value="Personal1"/>
 <add key="Documents_Folder" value="C:\Temp2\"/>
</appSettings>

some how, these above config file settings were not taken in my first answer.